# Can I specify php memory limit requirements in composer json? Perhaps in the "config.platform" node?

Tags: php, composer-php

I just got a memory limit error and I solved it in my .ini files.  No worries.  However, I'd like to put something in my package composer.json to indicated that some minimum memory is required.  I know how to specify a php version requirement in composer.json - I'm just wondering if other platform requirements can be added/checked by composer.

Comment: Composer can’t, but you should be able to include a [script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) with some additional checks. Just keep in mind that Composer usually runs in the commandline or a CI/CD pipeline, which may not have the same php.ini file and/or memory/platform constraints as the (webserver) environment your code will eventually run in.

Comment: Why not resolve the problem properly, by **fixing** the code that causes the memory limit to be exceeded?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's not my package and I don't want a fork of it.

Comment: You need to wrap any third-party code anyway, so regardless of whether you want to fork or not, your wrapper should at least do what @rickdenhaan wrote back in April.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Although this is the only working solution provided - please read the comment thread.  There are **good arguments against this**.  Also, this requires strong working knowledge of writing and deploying vendor packages.  Specifically, you'll want to know how to roll this back when a better solution is posted or the problematic package is fixed.

Add a little php file to your composer project or package.

**composer.json**

```
{
    ... 
    "autoload": {
        ...
        "files": ["tweak_ini.php"]
    }
}
```

**tweak_ini.php**

Obviously you'll want to add some logic to make sure you aren't downgrading.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');
...
```

Comment: While this may seem as a solution, it does not solve anything and only puts additional obstacles to the game. If you've got a deployment problem, discuss the issue with your server administrator. If this is a problem in the third party library, consult the developers of it, especially as OP does not want to fork. Everything else, again, is only begging for more problems (and as if the problem itself wouldn't be complex enough).

Comment: Hi @hakre - This is for both 3rd party and  1st party with meta packaging.

Comment: Well, I'd say it even counts more for 1st party. Probably think about a moment why it's (the memory limit) not within Composers `platform` meta-packages. While it is perfectly possible to "raise" the memory limit to `1000M`, the problem remains that the `platform` itself has a different limit and one of the packages actually requires `1500M` (or even more) to work and then you ruined it. And even if you only enlarge, the actual (concrete) platform has a hard limit you don't use the ini setting for anyway. In short: don't introduce PHP runtime configuration into the code if it's 1st/3rd party.

Comment: Hi @hakre - well, I don't need 1000, the post is just sample code.  I thought the size was kinda funny actually.  Anyway, deploying without manually adjusting or re-spawning servers is the solution that best suited our situation.  So I posted to try to be helpful.

Comment: If your server configuration is the problem, fix it in the configuration, don't (unnecessarily)  inject configuration at runtime for the whole application. That is only useless cycles, and, as commented before, creating more problems than you previously had. Yes it is possible what you do thanks to the powerful runtime, but apart from a hotfix to recover production operations, don't let it sink. Just saying, not judging. I know that it works, and that's why.

Comment: Hi @hakre, unfortunately we are stuck with package based distribution which is why I wrote the question the way I did.  We don't administer all the servers.  So, I think we have a stop-gap measure in place with this solution until someone posts a better one.  You make good points tho, and we didn't put this out without a way to roll it back (composer meta packaging).  It's a stop-gap.

Answer (score 1):

Composer can check for software to verify if they are corresponding. But, it doesn't check the system (CPU, memory...). You can specify the requirements in a readme.md file.

You can add in your code the memory limit needed in your script. But, in general, the default memory limit is enough. You may be have loops you can optimize by adding yeld or iterators.

Comment: Hi svgta, are you familiar with this kind of composer.json node? "config": {"platform": {"php": "7.4"}   I'd like to provide memory requirements in the package composer file.  Do you know how to do this?  Can it be done?

Comment: No, you can't specify memory requirements in composer. It's why you have to put it in your package a readme.md file with what is needed.

Comment: Ok, once in a while people like Sebastian / Taylor / Matt / etc chime in on these kinds of questions so I'll leave the question up.  Maybe one if them will change composer.  Some ref to ini requirements might not be the dumbest thing they've ever heard.

Comment: Nils and Jordi would be the relevant names in this case, and I don't remember seeing either of them on here. You'd be better off raising an actual feature request at https://github.com/composer/composer/issues

Answer (score 0):

The [complete list of properties available in composer.json](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) is very well-documented.

The only one which makes requirements on a user's system is the `require` section. This can include [platform dependencies](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/composer-platform-dependencies.md) (also discussed [on the "basic usage" page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages)) in the form of virtual packages exposing the version of PHP, its extensions and related libraries, and Composer itself. These are resolved as part of the dependency resolution process, and not when the application runs, although you can enable an additional [platform check](https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md#platform-check).

Note that the `config` section configures the behaviour of Composer itself, not the package, and is marked "root-only" - that is, it will not even be read when another project uses your library. The [`platform` option](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) which you've mentioned is the *opposite* of a platform requirement: it tells Composer to *pretend* certain constraints are met even when they are not.

If you want to verify at run-time that a particular configuration is in place, rather than merely documenting it, you can easily write your own using functions such as [ini_get](https://php.net/ini_get). This can either be run as part of initialisation of some relevant object or function, or listed as a [file include in the `autoload` section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) so that it will always be executed as the application starts up.